# Possible to import PHP into MXML?

Tags: php, mxml

I am having a (long) php file I want to include in my MXML. Is there an easy way to do this?

After googling around I found out that it's maybe possible to do it this way:

```
<fx:Script>
        <[[
            include "phpfile.php";
        ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

But this is wrong. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You can't do it in that way,  not possible

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not possible. But it's possible to generate a mxml file from a php script and then embed any php file to any part of the generated file.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but you cannot include a php file within a mxml one, if you want to use some php function you'll have to link your mxml to a php class containing all your stuff using Zend Framework.